How to format Jinja data structure with multiple key values?
Here is a template I am working on:
users:
{% for usr in users -%}
{# user {{ usr }} -#}
 - name: {{ users[usr].username }}
   passwd: {{ users[usr].hash }}
   ssh_authorized_keys: {{ users[usr].key }}
{% endfor %}

I have been using a Jinja parser to test the syntax/logic here: https://j2live.ttl255.com/
My question is, how would I format a dictionary/datastructure (what I think I need to use) to hold the data?
Example of the datastructure:
users:
  user1:
    username: queef
    hash: $6$eMRWO7k8SM
    key: 'sha-rsa $6$3EddsggdvX'
  user2:
    username: keagle
    hash: $6$eYYhaSqGDf45sEE
    key: '- sha-rsa $6$3AxxxX10HdvX'

Most examples I find online appear as a flat list, i.e.:
{% set my_dict = {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "New York"
} %}

Has anyone seen a multi key/value dictionary example?  I am only assuming this is the type of array I need to hold the values.
Since I can't store them in a separate JSON/YAML file, I need to hold the data in the Jinja template file somehow.
{% set users = ({"user1" 
                 "Username" : "queef",
                 "Hash" : "$6$eMRWO7k8SM",
                 "Key" : " - sha-rsa $6$3EddsggdvX", 
                 "user2" 
                 "Username" : "keagle",
                 "Hash" : "$6$eYYhaSqGDf45sEE",
                 "Key" : " - sha-rsa $6$3AxxxX10HdvX"  }) -%}

For Jinja to render the key values and output them during the for loop.
Error given:

Rendering error:
expected token ',', got ':'

What I am expecting it to output:
users:
- name: queef
  passwd: $6$eMRWO7k8SM
  ssh_authorized_keys: - sha-rsa $6$3EddsggdvX
- name: keagle
  passwd: $6$eYYhaSqGDf45sEE
  ssh_authorized_keys: - sha-rsa $6$3AxxxX10HdvX



Most examples I find online appear as a flat list, i.e.:
{% set my_dict = {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "New York" } %} 


Mind that this is not a list but a dictionary.
And the data structure you are showing in YAML is a mapping of mappings, so in Jinja/Python a dictionary of dictionaries.
So here is its representation in Jinja:
{%- set users = {
  "user1": {
    "username": "queef",
    "hash": "$6$eMRWO7k8SM",
    "key": "sha-rsa $6$3EddsggdvX",
  },
  "user2": {
    "username": "keagle",
    "hash": "$6$eYYhaSqGDf45sEE",
    "key": "- sha-rsa $6$3AxxxX10HdvX",
  },
} -%}


As for you confusion on structuring your data, you could go with a simpler list:
{%- set users = [
  {
    "username": "queef",
    "hash": "$6$eMRWO7k8SM",
    "key": "sha-rsa $6$3EddsggdvX",
  },
  {
    "username": "keagle",
    "hash": "$6$eYYhaSqGDf45sEE",
    "key": "- sha-rsa $6$3AxxxX10HdvX",
  },
] -%}

users:
{% for usr in users -%}
 - name: {{ usr.username }}
   passwd: {{ usr.hash }}
   ssh_authorized_keys: {{ usr.key }}
{% endfor %}

Or stay with a dictionary and use the username as key of your users, using the syntax for key, value in my_dict.items() as documented:
{%- set users = {
  "queef": {
    "hash": "$6$eMRWO7k8SM",
    "key": "sha-rsa $6$3EddsggdvX",
  },
  "keagle": {
    "hash": "$6$eYYhaSqGDf45sEE",
    "key": "- sha-rsa $6$3AxxxX10HdvX",
  },
} -%}

users:
{% for username, usr in users.items() -%}
 - name: {{ username }}
   passwd: {{ usr.hash }}
   ssh_authorized_keys: {{ usr.key }}
{% endfor %}

